# Активировать при наведении курсора

Tags: javascript, hover

На странице есть много блоков `<pre>текст</pre>`. Нужен скрипт, который при наведении курсора мыши и если дотронуться пальцем до блока, внутри блока `pre` активировалась кнопка HTML.

Вот так:

`<pre><button data-clipboard-target="pre">Copy</button>текс</pre>`

Это нужно чтобы не создавать для каждого блока id или класс, и кнопку под них.

Comment: Попробовал метод `<pre onmouseover="mOver(this)" onmouseout="mOut(this)", а innerHTML='<button data-clipboard-target="pre">'` Но происходит замена, так не нужно конечно. P.S. jQury не подключаю, он здесь не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Вот работающий скрипт.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('pre').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).prepend('<button data-clipboard-target="pre">Copy</button>');
    },
    function() {
      $('pre button').remove();
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>текст</pre>
<pre>текст</pre>
<pre>текст</pre>
<pre>текст</pre>
<pre>текст</pre>
<pre>текст</pre>
<pre>текст</pre>
<pre>текст</pre>
<pre>текст</pre>
<pre>текст</pre>
<pre>текст</pre>
```

Comment: Есть решение на чистом JavaScript?

Comment: Вы можете переписать это на чистый js - код понятен по сути.

Comment: В js hover и функция prepend по другому работают. ВОПРОС ОТКРЫТ.

Comment: А что за командный тон? Я никому ничего не должен.

Comment: Нет нет, даже в мыслях не было. Спасибо за код. Скрипт Я написал, такие вещи нужно знать `event.target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<button>Copy</button>');`